# How to prevent blur(?) footage at the recording stage?

Tags: video-quality

My question comes in two parts. First, may I know if my assessment of the quality of the footage in this Youtube movie is correct in the first place.

Compare the frames around 2:07 of this movie:

(2:07)

with

the frames around 1:59:

(1:59)

The quality of the picture in the former seems better than the latter. I am not exactly sure what is the difference, I can't pinpoint. But this was my first reaction when I was watching the clip.

After close examination for a while, I can only guess that the former seems to be a bit more blurry, have softer edges, and seems to be a bit darker as well.

Is my analysis correct, and am I missing anything else?

Secondly, how could the quality of the latter been improved at the recording stage? Is it something that could have been set in the camera, or should a better camera been used, and if yes, what exact specifications in the new camera should be sought?

My guess is the former uses a production video cam, but the latter uses perhaps an action cam like the GoPro. But must we always have such suboptimal footage from action cams, or could a better setting be used?

(NOTE: I did not participate in the production at all in the clip, so I do not know whatsoever what cams were used etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question is "why is the footage of this camera blurry".

The answer to that would be: It is out of focus. Cameras have a focal point and everything straying away from that (spatially) will get blurry. You can see that the back-windows is in focus, meaning that the lens has its focal point further back.

Comment: oh! that's an insight for me, thank you. Is that the only reason? Has it not got to do with the quality of the camera or sensor etc.?

Comment: There are many things that play into the quality of your captured image. However, pulling focus is one of the basics which are required to achieve a good image in the first place. Even when you're shooting with an iMax Camera, if your focus is off, the image will look bad. I would say for quality of image, these are the factors in order of importance: Lighting, Framing, Focus, Camera-Sensor, Lens.